# Linked Server to Progress - inconsistent metadata

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server, openedge, progress-db

I'm working on a systems integration with Progress (10.2B SP6). I'm using SQL 2012 and the Progress ODBC 64-bit driver. I created a linked server and the majority of my queries work, but queries against 3 tables fail with this message

Msg 7353, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "progress" supplied inconsistent metadata. An extra column was supplied during execution that was not found at compile time.

The two suggestions I found to fix it were changing lazy schema validation and recreating the linked server.

So this works:

```
SELECT Col1 FROM OPENQUERY(Progress, 'select Col1 from DB.pub.Table')
```

but this gives the above error

```
select Col1 from progress.DB.pub.Table
```

The query works fine using Razor SQL and the same ODBC driver, but I need to use a linked server, as the actual query will run from a scheduled SQL job, extract data and insert into SQL.

My actual query needs to join to this table. I could work around it by loading a ton of records into a temp table and joining to that, but it's gonna be way too inefficient

Anyone come across this or have any suggestions?

Regards

Mark

Comment: Suggestion for a similar error in the knowledge base: "use openquery". http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000002244

Comment: You should use openquery anyway.  Otherwise you are probably going to have some serious performance issues.

Comment: Thanks Tom, never really used OpenQuery. Can it be used with a full  complex query (over 100 lines, several joins and parameters or local vars)

Comment: Forgot to mention working with openquery is real PITA (unless I'm missing something). It's just like dynamic sql: escaping quotes, no  syntax checking, coloring, code formatting, etc. Every fiber of my being tells me I should be using it